# Add thousand point to a innerHTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning Javascript and I'm making a calculator but I cannot add the thousand point to my results, in the first function (formatearNumber) I can convert to thousand points the value that I put in the textbox but I cannot do the same to the results, here is my code:

```
 function formatNumber(myElement) { // Insert thousand separators to the first value
    var myVal = ""; // The number part
    var myDec = ""; // The digits pars
    // Splitting the value in parts using a dot as decimal separator
    var parts = myElement.value.toString().split(".");
    // Filtering out the trash!
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/[^0-9]/g,""); 
    // Setting up the decimal part
    if ( ! parts[1] && myElement.value.indexOf(".") > 1 ) { myDec = ".00" }
    if ( parts[1] ) { myDec = "."+parts[1] }
    // Adding the thousand separator
    while ( parts[0].length > 3 ) {
        myVal = ","+parts[0].substr(parts[0].length-3, parts[0].length )+myVal;
        parts[0] = parts[0].substr(0, parts[0].length-3)
    }
    myElement.value = parts[0]+myVal+myDec;
}
function multiply() {
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    price=price.replace(/\,/g,'');
    price=parseInt(price,10);
    var save = document.getElementById("save").value;
    var result = price * save / 100 * 20;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}

function value1() {
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    price=price.replace(/\,/g,'');
    price=parseInt(price,10);
    var save = document.getElementById("save").value;
    var result = price * save / 100 * 20;
    var value1 = result / 4;
    document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = value1;
}

    function monthvalue() {
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    price=price.replace(/\,/g,'');
    price=parseInt(price,10);
    var save = document.getElementById("save").value;
    var result = price * save / 100 * 20;
    var value1 = result / 4;
    var first = result - value1;
    var monthvalue = first / 20;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue1").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue2").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue3").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue4").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue5").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue6").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue7").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue8").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue9").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue10").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue11").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue12").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue13").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue14").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue15").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue16").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue17").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue18").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue19").innerHTML = monthvalue;
    document.getElementById("monthvalue20").innerHTML = monthvalue;
}
```

To insert the thousand in the HTML textbox I'm using formatNumber(this) and to show the results in the page I only use id="result" or id="value1" or id="monthvalue1" to each one of my innerHTML, if you can show me a better way to do it I'll be very grateful.

Comment: An operation like this is most easily achieved with `.toFixed` and a _RegularExpression_, e.g. `1234567890.12345.toFixed(4).replace(/(?=(?:\d{3})+?\D)/g, ' ');` gives the nicely formatted
`"1 234 567 890.1235"`

Comment: If you want to include cases where there is no decimal point in my above example, don't one line it - you would need to `.split('.')`, _replace_ on index `0` and `.join('.')` together again

Comment: Thank you, I try this but when I use toFixed(4).replace(/(?=(?:\d{3})+?\D)/g, ' '); and change for toFixed(4).replace(/(?=(?:\d{3})+?\D)/g, ','); to use the comma, I obtained a comma at start of the string.

Comment: Forgot that case `/(?!\D|^)(?=(?:\d{3})+?\D)/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)? It works in almost all modern browsers, and would save you from having to re-invent the wheel:

```
var number = 1234567.89
number.toLocaleString('en'); // 1,234,567.89
number.toLocaleString('fr'); // 1 234 567,89
```

Comment: Thank you this is a really good solution, my code now uses:     var resultunf = price * save / 100 * 20; var result = resultadunf.toLocaleString('en');
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;

Comment: Please note that the behaviour of `.toLocaleString` is (per spec [**ES5**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.3), [**ES6**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.prototype.tolocalestring)) `implementation-dependent` and therefore you should not assume the output will be formatted as desired